# Adding powerpoint slides using matlab: Error using mlreportgen.ppt.Presentation/add Could not find layout: 'Blank'

Tags: matlab, powerpoint

I'm trying to add slides to a pre-existing powerpoint using matlab's powerpoint package. However, I get the following error that it cannot find a layout named 'Blank' even though powerpoint has 'Blank' layouts. The error is the following:
Error using mlreportgen.ppt.Presentation/add Could not find layout: 'Blank'

Comment: Ah, my original code is much more complicated and pulls inputs from multiple places. I quickly changed my original code to post here and forgot to remove the extra brackets. Please ignore them for this purpose.

Comment: What is `new_slides`? Is it a valid path to a file?